# Buying a 'first' home while having fractional ownership of another (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate, homeownership

The United Kingdom offers a [special program](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/first-homes) for first-time home buyers who meet certain qualifying criteria.

Does a person who previously purchased a minority share (e.g. 20%) of a house qualify for this program? If not, is there a way for this person to become eligible?

Comment: While the stamp duty is a legal question, the LTV requirement is simply a business policy of a commercial bank that probably doesn't have the force of law. Different banks could have different rules for a situation like this one (although there may be strong norms on how to calculate LTV requirements that are shared by most banks).

Comment: Edited to not ask for specific legal advice in accordance with site guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No and no.

The definition of a "first-time buyer" for the purposes of the First Homes program is given by paragraph 6 of [schedule 6ZA of the Finance Act](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/14/schedule/6ZA), which provides that:

> In this Schedule “first-time buyer” means an individual who—
> (a) has not previously been a purchaser in relation to a land transaction the main subject-matter of which was a major interest in a dwelling [...].

A "major interest" is defined by [Section 117 of the Finance Act](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/14/section/117/2018-04-01) to include an "an estate in fee simple absolute or a term of years absolute", subject to a few limiting statements that are not relevant here, without any limiting provision about how *much* of that interest is required to count as major. Accordingly, the common interpretation is that no matter how small it is, an equity share of a property counts as a "major interest" if it's a share of a freehold or leasehold.

Under the law as it stands now, there is no way to become eligible once someone has acquired a major interest. It does not matter if that person then sells their share, because an individual is eligible only if that individual "*has not previously been* a purchaser [...]" (emphasis added).